# MDX combine LEFT & INSTR functions

Tags: conditional-statements, mdx

What is wrong on this boolean condition?

```
(
Left(
  [Article].[Main Article Alternative ID CPG].currentmember.Properties('Member_Caption')
  ,(Instr( 
      [Article].[Main Article Alternative ID CPG].currentmember.Properties('Member_Caption')
      , ' ' 
    )-1)
 )='ABC'
)
```

error in saying: -1 parameter out of valid range

Comment: e.g. works... (Left([Article].[Main Article Alternative ID CPG].currentmember.Properties( 'Member_Caption' ),(Instr('OPRS' + ' ',' ')-2))='ABC')

Answer (score 0):

This is fine: `=Instr("OPRS" + " "," ")` as the string you are searching for is in the string.

You have the following:

```
LEFT(
  [Article].[Main Article Alternative ID CPG].currentmember.Member_Caption
  ,INSTR( 
        [Article].[Main Article Alternative ID CPG].currentmember.Member_Caption             
      , ' ' 
   )-1
 )='ABC'
```

If `' '` is not found then `INSTR([Article].[Main Article Alternative ID CPG].currentmember.Member_Caption , ' ')` returns 0 and there for you will have `LEFT("xxx", -1)`  and hence the invalid parameter exception.

You could add an initial check:

```
IIF(
  INSTR( 
            [Article].[Main Article Alternative ID CPG].currentmember.Member_Caption             
          , ' ' 
       ) = 0
   ,NULL
   ,LEFT(
      [Article].[Main Article Alternative ID CPG].currentmember.Member_Caption
      ,INSTR( 
            [Article].[Main Article Alternative ID CPG].currentmember.Member_Caption             
          , ' ' 
       )-1
     )='ABC'
)
```